# PropertyChangedCallback not updating GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

hi i have one mainWindow which passing a live sensor data to usercontrol chart under the same GUI interface  , and PropertyChangedCallback seems does not update any GUI content( chart does not receive any data) , find my code below :

1. MainWindow.xaml

   ```
   <local:ConstantChangeChart1 x:Name="cscs"></local:ConstantChangeChart1>
   ```
2. MainWindow.xaml.cs

   ```
   cscs.SetValue(ConstantChangeChart1.MyCustomProperty, main_liveValue_lbl.Content);
   ```
3. Usercontrol - ConstantChangeChart1

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustom", typeof(string), typeof(ConstantChangeChart1),
       new PropertyMetadata(
       new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyCustomChanged)));

   public string MyCustom
   {
       get
       {
           return this.GetValue(MyCustomProperty) as string;
       }
       set
       {
           this.SetValue(MyCustomProperty, value);
           OnPropertyChanged("MyCustom");
       }
   }
   public static void OnMyCustomChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       ConstantChangeChart1 originator = d as ConstantChangeChart1;
       if (originator != null)
       {
           originator.OnMyPropertyChanged(d,e);
       }
   }

   private void OnMyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d ,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       ConstantChangeChart1 control = (ConstantChangeChart1)d;
       if(control !=null)
       {
           //Thread.Sleep(150);
           var now = DateTime.Now;
           //_trend += r.Next(-8, 10);

           this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
           {
               ChartValues.Add(new Model.MeasureModel
               {
                   DateTime = now,
                   Value = Convert.ToDouble(MyCustom)
               });
           });

           SetAxisLimits(now);

           //lets only use the last 150 values
           if (ChartValues.Count > 150) ChartValues.RemoveAt(0);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: anyone can help ?

Comment: What is ChartValues?